# Django - Jinja2 caching of template variables

Tags: django, caching

Before Jinja2 i was using a custom context_processor for caching (objects list ) via memcached.

```
#context_processors.py    
def pikto_studio_caching(request:None, sender:None, **kwargs):
        cache_time = 60*60*24
        cache_key_works = 'pikto_studio:works'

        works = cache.get(cache_key_works)

        if request:
            if not works:
                works = Work.objects.all()
                cache.set(cache_key_works, works, cache_time)
            return {'WORKS':works}
        else:
            cache._cache.flush_all()
            return None
```

With jinja2 i can't use context_processors. How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create jinja2.py file, add your caching function to Jinja2 environment globals.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import defaultfilters
from jinja2 import Environment


#CACHING
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from apps.web.models import Work, CategoryWork, BasicArticle, CategoryBasicArticle

def caching(request=None, sender=None, **kwargs):
    cache_time = 60*60*24
    cache_key_works = 'pikto_studio:works'

    works = cache.get(cache_key_works)

    if request:
        if not works:
            works = Work.objects.all()
            cache.set(cache_key_works, works, cache_time)
        return {'works':works}
    else:
        cache._cache.flush_all()
        return None



def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)

    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
        'caching':caching,

    })
    return env
```

call the function in the template :

```
{% set works = caching(request)['works'] %}
    {% for work in works %}
     {{ work.title }}
{% endfor %}
```